# Is there a way to buy cheap health potions?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can you buy half priced potions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72781/where-can-you-buy-half-priced-potions)

I am constantly in need of new potions in Inferno and I have to invest quite some gold in this. Buying 10 potions costs 6.100 gold. This is not much but it adds up. Especially jumping to a higher Act burns through my potions.

I think I remember some NPC selling cheap potions after some event, but I am not sure.

Is there some way to buy potions for less than the common vendor price of 610 gold?

It does not matter if this is very rare, as I would buy like 300 or more at a time.

Comment: There are various vendors that sell potions at various rates. A quick trip to youtube would demonstrate several of these vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awesome answer:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/72782/25490